# how to use the latest build gradle in old android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android studio version 3.4.2 but the my project says: `ERROR: This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer.`

But when I upgraded Android studio, I found some bugs that are terrible, which slows down my productivity. One of them is this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153711336

So, I downgraded Android Studio again to 3.4.2.

Then I tried changing the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

and also have changed `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`

just to run the project in the older Android studio. But then I see this error:
`error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.`

Seems like, it needs the latest build gradle.

I don't wanna upgrade Android studio again, just to upgrade build gradle. at least not until the layout editor bug is fixed. But I have to do run this project too. Now, I'm not sure what to do. Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: try using gradle 4.0.1

Comment: I don't wanna upgrade android studio from 3.4.2, that's the main point of asking this question. cause, upgraded version of Android studio has a very buggy layout editor

Comment: Android 11 introduced ```<queries>``` as a manifest element, and older versions of the Android Gradle Plugin do not know about that element.

Comment: So the easier way is to update or else remove the features that are not compatible with the older version (complex process)

Comment: I know about the queries, but why can't I just update the SDK and gradle without upgrading the Android Studio? I just don't want my layout editor to be messed up